# Gravitional bending of light in an eclipse of the sun, formation of an Einstein ring

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light, eclipse

Has it been observed that at Moon occultation of the Sun the bending of the light beam arriving from a distant stelar object behind the Sun is isotropic or the rotation of the Sun slightly modifies the ring of bent light around it?

Comment: That might be very difficult to observe, considering the Sun's slow rate of rotation. I assume you're talking about [frame dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a solar eclipse we don’t observe a ring of bent starlight. Light from a distant star behind the middle of the Sun wouldn’t get bent enough to reach the Earth. We can observe the deflection of starlight from stars at the edge of the Sun. The frame-dragging effect of the Sun’s rotation is too small to observe in this way.

The kind of [Einstein ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_ring) you’re talking about is caused by the light of a distant galaxy bending around a closer galaxy or black hole. As far as I know, frame-dragging cannot be observed there either. [Frame-dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging) has been verified by the GRACE and Gravity Probe B experiments, which did not use the deflection of starlight.